# Why no Ivy Bridge servers?

Tags: central-processing-unit, intel

It seems that Intel released server versions of their Ivy Bridge chips in [May of 2012](http://www.engadget.com/2012/05/15/intel-launches-new-ivy-bridge-xeons-targets-microservers/).  It's now October of 2012, why can't I buy a server with an Ivy Bridge chip?  When might I be able to?

Comment: A phone call to Intel could probably answer this for you.

Comment: Soon™ - or just ask the vendors.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear to me that it would.  They're not selling the servers, and I don't really know if they could tell me anything, hence the question here.

Comment: With the majority of us not being server manufacturers, I'm not sure how the Server Fault community could help you with this question.  This is something you really need to ask your hardware vendor ("When will I be able to buy a server from you with Intel's Ivy Bridge platform/chips?")

Comment: If you have a relationship with a server manufacturer, they'll share some details of their server roadmap with you. If details at this level of specific technologies matter significantly to you, cultivate at least one such relationship.

Answer (score 1):

They exist. The [E5-2400 series](http://ark.intel.com/products/series/64580), which is Ivy Bridge, is available in the HP [DL360e Gen8 series](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14328_na/14328_na.html#Standard), as well as the [Dell R320 series](http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/poweredge-r320/pd?~ck=anav).

Comment: This appears to disagree with the assertion that they are Ivy Bridge http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon#E5-16xx.2F24xx.2F26xx.2F46xx-series_.22Sandy_Bridge-EP.22 and indeed the page you linked says they are 32nm lithography.

Comment: @brooks94 As irony would have it, I ran into [these](http://www.dell.com/us/enterprise/p/poweredge-c5220/pd?~ck=anav) today while linking around. Those run the E3-1200v2 CPU you're interested in.